# How to detect Oauth window close?

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I'm using Oauth to subscribe to [Fitbit](https://www.fitbit.com/). When the user clicks a connect button in my website, he/she is redirected to the Fitbit authentication page, which open as a new tab in the browser, while it shows a loading progress bar in my website.

When user clicks the accept or deny button in the fitbit authentication page, fitbit pings my back end and everything works fine. But, if the user closes the window not opting to click neither accept nor deny, I'm stuck with the progress bar in my website. How can I get around this?

This is the how actually the progress bar closes. I use a column in my database called is_connected which returns the status of the connection

```
is_connected=0 // not connected 
is_connected=1 // connected
is_connected=2 // connecting
```

so while the progress bar is showing(is_connected=2), the frontend keeps on pinging the backend requesting the status of is_connected field. When it detects a change, the progress bar closes.